# How to remove dry water based urethane varnish from mirror?

Tags: cleaning, woodworking, varnishing

I recently varnished an hardwood frame for a mirror with a [water based urethane varnish](http://generalfinishes.com/professional-products/water-base-topcoats-and-sanding-sealers/enduro-var). My painter's tape did protect most of the mirror's edges, but it failed for one or two spots. The varnish found it's way under the tape. I want to get rid of the spots without scratching my mirror. I tried to use soap and water as suggested on my varnish's label, but that's clearly for when the varnish is not dry.  So, I'm wondering what's a good way to remove dry varnish from a mirror. Obviously, my top priority is not to scratch the mirror itself.

Comment: The chance of scratching glass with a razor scraper is slim to none.

Comment: nice sharp single sided razor blade in a handle works great.

Comment: Yup a single edge razor blade does the trick. What scratches the glass is when the blade gets dull or grit on the surface of the glass gets caught with the blade.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks everyone, I've used a razor blade with a handle and it worked great. I have no more varnish spots on my mirror!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor scrapper would work best with a little mineral spirits.

Comment: I actually didn't have to use mineral spirits.